# Adding a low voltage RAM to existing high voltage RAM laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3

I have a Dell Vostro 3558 laptop.

My existing RAM size 4GB. It is DDR3 (PC3-12800 800 MHz)
I have two slots in my laptop and one is unused.

I want to upgrade by 8GB or 4GB.

I understand low voltage can be used as well as it can save power but also searched and found comments saying mixing of voltages may not be good for laptops.

Can I buy a 8GB PC3L for my laptop or would you suggest anything else.

Below is snapshot of laptop RAM 
[image: RAM snapshot]

P.S.
Would highly Appreciate your suggestions.
And I am thinking to buy [this one](https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-1600MHz-DDR3L-Laptop-KVR16LS11/dp/B00CQ35HBQ/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=4GB%2BDDR3L%2BRam&qid=1579010944&s=computers&sr=1-2&th=1)

Comment: Chances are it will run all of the RAM at the same voltage, that being the lowest supported by all modules. The low voltage RAM will work at the same voltage as your old RAM and give no power saving at all. If your low voltage RAM does not support the higher voltage then your system will likely just not boot.

Comment: The RAM you have is already PC3L. PC3L works at either 1.35, but can also work at the higher 1.5V.

Comment: @Mokubai The link i have added is for the one i want to buy.. I am currently having DDR3/PC3(at least thats what the CPU-Z says..)

Comment: Your RAM is running at 1.35V. That is not "high voltage" which would be 1.5V. Looking up the actual part number for your RAM shows it is DDR3L: https://www.amazon.com/SAMSUNG-M471B5173QH0-YK0-PC3-12800-512MBX64-512MX8/dp/B00T592DGG CPU-z is simply not showing the "L" designation.

Comment: @Mokubai thank you so much! I have finally bought this one https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00KEAEVPG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1